# Can any one guide me how to start a simple web page using Umbraco CMS?

Tags: c#, asp.net, content-management-system, umbraco

I have installed Umbraco CMS and created a page with "WebForm1.aspx" but it is showing the error when i am trying to run the project.

```
Page not found

No umbraco document matches the url '/WebForm1.aspx'.

This page can be replaced with a custom 404. Check the documentation for "custom 404".
```

Where am doing wrong in this process can any one help me out by providing a way?
.
thanks a lot

Comment: Yes, Umbraco website can help:
https://umbraco.com/follow-us/blog-archive/2014/1/29/start-with-umbraco-v7,-free-foundation-tutorials-on-umbracotv.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your quick replay @Oscar, will you provide me any working example if it is, then it is a great help for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already explained in the comments, there are guides on how to do it, but I'll just go through the steps quickly:

First, go to settings, and create a new template (Your .aspx file). This is the actual definition of the design on the page.

Then go to Document Types, and create a new one, making sure to check the above template as allowed. This defines a type of page users may create and the Umbraco backend, and which designs it's compatible with.

Then go to Content, and create a new document of the above document type - selecting the template you created as template. (You may need to add your newly created document type to the list of allowed types (structure tab) under the document type of your root node).

After you've created it, make sure to publish - and there you have it.